# How does StorageEvent work in Office Add-in?

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

I have 2 task panes in Word Add-in (using Office UI Fabric with React). I select item in first pane and then I write item's id to localStorage. In the second pane I press update button, so I can see details of the item.

I want to avoid pressing update button. So I tried adding `window.addEventListener('storage', f)` in the second pane, but it doesn't trigger.

Am I doing something wrong?
or
Does Add-in interpret itself as single window and that's why StorageEvent is not triggered?

And what alternatives do I have?
(`Office.context.document.settings`, `SharedWorker`, ...?)

Comment: Try the syntax window.addEventListener instead of window.eventListener.

Comment: Sorry, it's typo in question, not in the actual code :)

Comment: My question is basically - how to communicate within task panes?  
p.s. Can't use SharedWorker because IE doesn't support it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've consulted with the Office product team. Their experience is that the storage event does not fire reliably in add-ins, and that this is probably a problem with IE. They recommend that you poll local storage instead of relying on the event.

Comment: I guess I can use hidden elements - `customXmlParts` or smth that has support for change event, but this can be overhead. So yea, I just poll local storage. Thanks for your help :)